# Why is it not possible to use present perfect in this case?

Tags: present-tense

I wrote a note after ordering both records:

> Please do not send until the other records from the series **have been out**.

Why can I not use present perfect? Present in this case is better.

I don't understand why the present perfect does not fit here if I want to emphasize the date of release.

Comment: +1 Good question. Well..answer? Sorry I don't know perfectly:).

Comment: I mean, it is the present perfect, isn't it? When I looked at the first time and upvoted, it was **had been out**....

Comment: no it was "have been" i have not changed it

Comment: So are you asking "why here the present perfect **continuous** is used"? I'm getting perplexed. In my mind, there is the present perfect (in a broader sense) there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the present perfect, it's just that your sentence is not idiomatic.

> Please do not send them until the other records from the series **have come out**.

We say that the record **is out**, or that the record **has come out**.

> Please do not send them until the other records from the series **are out**.

This is also a good way of expressing your meaning.

Comment: Yeah, your answer is simple and clear and fine.